Cached credentials not working on win 11 domain joined desktop
I have an issue with my own desktop, which is almost certainly due to me experimenting with something or other, I just have no idea what, or when.
On my desktop, and only on my desktop, I cannot log in when it doesn't have access to the DC. I get an error stating that its not possible to comunicate with a domain controller. Obviously this is annoying when I'm the one who has to resolve network and server issues.
I don't have a GPO which changes the default cached credential setting. If I execute
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v CachedLogonsCount
it returns 10, type REG_SZ
possibly relevant and found by searching the registry:
reg query "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\LocalPoliciesSecurityOptions" /v InteractiveLogon_NumberOfPreviousLogonsToCache
also returns 10, Type REG_SZ
I thought maybe there might be something under HLKM\\Software\Microsoft\Policies but none of the settings under this seem to be credential related.
What other settings can afect the behaviour of cached logins?
